# Doing an SQL query in PHP that depends on a variable

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I´m trying to do the following query in PHP

```
            $sqlstr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales where passport = $row['passport']");
            if (mysql_numrows($sqlstr) != 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlstr)) {
            echo $row['firstname']; 
            }}
```

How can I incorporate the value of $row['passport'] into my query?

Comment: It looks like you have?! What's the printed output of your SQL query?

Answer (score 7):

First of all you forgot the single-quotes. sAc corrected this already in his answer. But I would consider to also use an escaping function due to security-issues:

```
$sqlstr = mysql_query("
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sales
WHERE
    passport = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($row['passport']) . "'");
```

Comment: It's not only for security reasons: you don't want data corruption or program crashing.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing quotes:

```
$sqlstr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales where passport = '{$row['passport']}'");
```

Answer (score 5):

I would avoid manually escaping/sanitizing your variables and just use prepared statements. This was something I didn't learn until much later in my web development career, and I wish I'd known about it sooner. It will save you a lot of trouble and is just safer all around.

You can use the [`mysqli_stmt` class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to perform MySQL queries using prepared statements, or you could use the [PHP Data Objects (PDO) extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), which works with MySQL, PostgreSQL and other RDBMSes.

Just to show you what it looks like, here's the first example from the [`PDOStatement->bindParam` doc page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```